# How to resolve Autofac per-request service from custom attribute

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have configured my EF context configured like so

```
        b.RegisterAssemblyTypes(webAssembly, coreAssembly)
            .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<DbContext>())
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I would like to use it from a custom authorization attribute that hits the database using my EF context. This means no constructor-injection. I achieve this by using [CommonSeviceLocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/)

```
        var csl = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => csl);
```

...

```
        var user = await ServiceLocator.Current
           .GetInstance<SiteContext>().FindAsync(id);
```

I am finding that this fails with a "multiple connections not supported" error if the browser issues two simultaneous requests to routes using this attribute. It seems like this might be [due to what is mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23356038/5056). My guess is that `ServiceLocator` resolves from the root scope rather than the web request scope and the two request are conflicting (either request in isolation works fine).

This seems confirmed by that when I change to `InstancePerRequest()` I get this from any invocation of the attribute.

```
 Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is
 being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container  itself.
```

So it seems like maybe `ServiceLocator` is simply not the way to go.

How do I resolve the request-scoped `SiteContext` from inside the attribute (using a service-locator pattern)?

Comment: [Standard Web API Filters are Singletons](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filters-are-singletons). You can check here.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel yes, but its not like the `ServiceLocator` caches the response, it gets a new one on each invocation! My guess is that the filter code runs *before* Autofac creates its request scope.

Comment: It will get new one with each request but it will share this with controller in that request. (I have tested to be sure).

Comment: @ErkanDemirel that's exactly what I want though, and that is not what is happening. Most components will do this, however the attribute seems to use a singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue derives from the fact that you are trying to put *behavior* inside of an Attribute. Attributes are for defining *meta-data* on code elements and assemblies, not for behavior.

Microsoft's marketing of Action Filter Attributes has led people implementing DI down the wrong path by putting both the Filter and the Attribute into the same class. As described in the post [passive attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/), the solution is to break apart [filter attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) into 2 classes:

1. An attribute that contains no behavior to mark code elements with meta-data.
2. A globally-registered filter that scans for the attribute and executes the desired behavior if present.

See the following for more examples:

- [Constructor Dependency Injection WebApi Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352680/constructor-dependency-injection-webapi-attributes/28365933#28365933)
- [Unity Inject dependencies into MVC filter class with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235660/unity-inject-dependencies-into-mvc-filter-class-with-parameters#32254851)
- [Implementing passive attributes with dependencies that should be resolved by a DI container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433608/implementing-passive-attributes-with-dependencies-that-should-be-resolved-by-a-d)
- [Dependency Injection in Attributes: don’t do it!](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98)
- [Injecting dependencies into ASP.NET MVC 3 action filters. What's wrong with this approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192543/injecting-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-3-action-filters-whats-wrong-with-this/7194467#7194467)
- [How can I test for the presence of an Action Filter with constructor arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245220/how-can-i-test-for-the-presence-of-an-action-filter-with-constructor-arguments/27470397#27470397)

Another option is to use `IFilterProvider` to resolve the filters as in [IFilterProvider and separation of concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708565/ifilterprovider-and-separation-of-concerns).

Once you get your head around the fact that Attributes should not be doing anything themselves, using them with DI is rather straightforward.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying...but in the first example at least wouldn't that have the same problem? The filter is resolved in the global scope - not in the `AutofacWebRequest` scope - and would therefore be a singleton. If the attribute itself has only one instance then all lifecycles are still the same as with a service-locator pattern, aren't they?

Comment: As Erkan pointed out in the comments, there are 2 ways around that issue 1) use the Autofac interfaces rather than WebAPI interfaces 2) use a service locator from the dependency scope (which is passed in through the context). See [the examples](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filters-are-singletons). There is a possible 3rd option that is more DI-friendly - inject an [abstract factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) to create your `SiteContext` instance within the action filter rather than using a service locator.

Comment: ah, I think 2) is what I want. Obviously DI Friendly stuff is better so I might try that first, but for a bit of isolated infrastructure like this...meh...

Comment: This works fairly well, although getting the presence of an attribute can be a fun puzzle in and of itself. For webapi filters it is: Enumerable.Any(actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAttribute>());